# Drop columns by patterns values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as :

```
g1   g2   g3   g4   g5
2    0    1    0    1
2    1    1    0    1
2    1    1    2    1
```

and I would like to remove each column that have at least one 2 in its values.

and get a new df :

```
g2   g3   g5
0    1    1
1    1    1
1    1    1
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `df[vapply(df, function(x) all(x!=2),TRUE)]`

Answer (score 5):

We can use `colSums` here:

```
df <- data.frame(g1=c(2,2,2), g2=c(0,1,1), g3=c(1,1,1), g4=c(0,0,2), g5=c(1,1,1))
df[, !colSums(df==2)]

  g2 g3 g5
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  1  1
```

The idea is to include all rows from the original data frame, but only include those columns which never have a value of 2.  In that case, the call to `colSums()` would be zero, which is logically equivalent to `false` in R.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `select_if` function with a predicate function to achieve this.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>% select_if(function(x) !any(x == 2))
dat2
#   g2 g3 g5
# 1  0  1  1
# 2  1  1  1
# 3  1  1  1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "g1   g2   g3   g4   g5
2    0    1    0    1
                  2    1    1    0    1
                  2    1    1    2    1",
                      header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Same idea in base R: `Filter(function(x) !any(x == 2), dat)`

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `purrr`:

```
df[,map_lgl(df,~sum(.x==2)<1)]


   g2 g3 g5
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  1  1
```